# Gmaps add an event to a link in a marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have a littele problem

It's possible add a event CLICK to a link in a marker in gmaps v3?

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: position,
    html: "<a id='link'>mylink</a>",
    icon: '/images/repairer.png'
});
gmarkers.push(m);

  $('#link').click(function () {    
          alert($(this).attr('data'));
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function () {
 info_window.setContent(this.html);
 info_window.open(map, this);
});
```

HELP

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#your_map_id').on('click', '#link',function () {    
          alert($(this).attr('data'));
    });
```

Comment: $('#service_center').on('click',   '#OpenDetailsFromMarker'+gm,function () {  
             alert($(this).attr('data'));      });


don't work

Comment: @user2437305 try with `$('#service_center').on('click', 'a',function () {  alert($(this).attr('data'));  }`